# Assigning a function to button does not work

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

So I have this code, running multiple GUI windows in tkinter, I also have the second code that contains a certain function assigned to a button, that seems not to work. Im extremely tired and can't find the solution, I'm sure it's some basic thing. The function I mean is the toggle_text1 command in the PageOne class. I'll appreciate every help, thanks!

```
import Tkinter as tk

TITLE_FONT = ("Helvetica", 18, "bold")

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=False)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo, Page3, Page4):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, c):
        '''Show a frame for the given class'''
        frame = self.frames[c]
        frame.tkraise()

    def toggle_text1():

        if button1["text"] == "WL":
            button1["text"] = "WYL"
            label1["bg"] = "green"
            #wiringpi.pinMode(91,0)
            #wiringpi.digitalWrite(91,0)

        else:

            button1["text"] = "WL"
            label1["bg"] = "red"
            #wiringpi.pinMode(91,1)
            #wiringpi.digitalWrite(91,0)


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="left", fill="x", pady=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page One",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page Two",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page 3",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page3))
        button4 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page 4",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page4))
        button1.pack(pady=10)
        button2.pack(pady=10)
        button3.pack(pady=10)
        button4.pack(pady=10)
```

Oh crap, I've deleted the widget earlier and forgot to paste it again, my bad. How about now?

```
class PageOne(tk.Frame):


    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text='WL', command=toggle_text1)
        button.pack()
        button1.pack()
        label1.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: *"Im extremely tired and can't find the solution, I'm sure it's some basic thing"* - then go to sleep and try again in the morning. SO isn't here to do basic debugging for you.

Comment: When I search for `toggle_text1`, I don't see anywhere that you actually use that function with a button.

Comment: Sorry, my bad I've deleted the widget, and now repasted it, can you check it now?

Comment: This is what happens when you copy/paste code without understanding it. The solution to your question is literally on the line immediately preceding the button code you're asking about. Don't simply copy code from stackoverflow, _learn_ from it.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, well maybe I shuld've started by doing this code from scratch, you're right but I'm looking for various ways to make this multiple windowed GUI and implying the functions to the buttons, that's the one that ovegrew me, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your function and button are in different classes if you want to use a function from one class in another, then you need to pass it into your constructor. Which is what you have done.

```
for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo, Page3, Page4):
    frame = F(container, self)
```

You have passed it in as controller

```
class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
```

Therefore when assigning the function you need to prefix it with `controller`

```
button1 = tk.Button(self, text='WL', command=controller.toggle_text1)
```

Which you have done for all your lambda functions. Also you need to add self as an argument to your function

Comment: I did as you said, the function now looks like this:
def toggle_text1(self):

        if button1["text"] == "WL":
            button1["text"] = "WYL"
            label1["bg"] = "green"

        else:

            button1["text"] = "WL"
            label1["bg"] = "red"


When I execute the code and proceed to use the button i get this error message
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/Sky System/untitled/multwind2.py", line 36, in toggle_text1
    if button1["text"] == "WL":
NameError: global name 'button1' is not defined

Comment: I'm not sure how could I solve this, since the button1 is defined in PageOne class I don't know how to indicate the button needed for the function

Comment: Ah I see. You need to assign button1 as a variable of PageOne class which looks like `self._button1 = tk.Button(self, text='WL', command=self.toggle_text1)` and in the function prefix each instance of `button1` with `self.frames[PageOne]` which I assume is a dictionary so it would look like `if self.frames[PageOne].button1["text"] == "WL":`